# Unable to install Tidyverse. Broom issues

Tags: r, tidyverse, broom

Whenever I try to install tidyverse in R v 3.6.2

I receive the following error message:

```
Installing package into ‘C:/Users/daeb/Documents/R/win-library/3.6’
(as ‘lib’ is unspecified)
also installing the dependency ‘broom’


  There is a binary version available but the source version is later:
      binary source needs_compilation
broom  0.5.3  0.5.4             FALSE

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/bin/windows/contrib/3.6/tidyverse_1.3.0.zip'
Content type 'application/zip' length 440101 bytes (429 KB)
downloaded 429 KB

package ‘tidyverse’ successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked

The downloaded binary packages are in
    C:\Users\daeb\AppData\Local\Temp\RtmpuWXq4I\downloaded_packages
installing the source package ‘broom’

trying URL 'https://cran.rstudio.com/src/contrib/broom_0.5.4.tar.gz'
Content type 'application/x-gzip' length 1228129 bytes (1.2 MB)
downloaded 1.2 MB

* installing *source* package 'broom' ...
** package 'broom' successfully unpacked and MD5 sums checked
** using staged installation
** R
** data
*** moving datasets to lazyload DB
** inst
** byte-compile and prepare package for lazy loading
Fejl i loadNamespace(j <- i[[1L]], c(lib.loc, .libPaths()), versionCheck = vI[[j]]) : 
  there is no package called 'zeallot'
Kald: <Anonymous> ... loadNamespace -> withRestarts -> withOneRestart -> doWithOneRestart
Kørsel stoppet
ERROR: lazy loading failed for package 'broom'
* removing 'C:/Users/daeb/Documents/R/win-library/3.6/broom'
Warning in install.packages :
  installation of package ‘broom’ had non-zero exit status
```

I have tried reinstalling both R and Rstudio but it does not solve the problem. I tried installing Rtools, but it does not work either. It appears I have to solve the source/binary issue with broom but I do not know how.

Comment: You should try `install.packages("zeallot")` and then install tidyverse again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As @hplieninger suggests, the proximal problem is that the installation of broom is looking for the `zeallot` package, which isn't installed:

> there is no package called 'zeallot'

You should try manually installing the `zeallot` package (`install.packages("zeallot")`) and then try installing tidyverse again.

It might also help to say "no" when R asks you whether you want to install the packages with more recent source-code versions from source rather than binary.  (The worst thing that can happen is that you end up with slightly older versions of some packages.)

**However** it's surprising that this requirement comes up. Are you using `install.packages("tidyverse")`?  Are you specifying something like `dependencies=TRUE`?

Because according to the CRAN index pages

- The [current version of broom](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/broom/index.html) (0.5.4, apparently the same version that R is trying to install for you)  doesn't directly import `zeallot`: it `Depends` only on R and

> Imports: backports, dplyr, generics (≥ 0.0.2), methods, nlme, purrr, reshape2, stringr, tibble, tidyr

- The [current version of zeallot](https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/zeallot/index.html) shouldn't obviously be needed. The packages that use it are:

> **Reverse imports:**  completejourney, graphTweets, ipumsr, keras, mlflow, statsExpressions
>   **Reverse suggests:**     listarrays, SDMtune, vctrs

Comment: Hi, I saw the problem of the zeallot package after posting this question and after installing it I could use the tidyverse package normally. So I solved the issue with that. And yes, I did try ´install.packages("tidyverse",dependencies=TRUE)´ but it did not work

Comment: if this answer solved your problem you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it ...